# How to use Express with Socket.io?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, socket.io

I have the Express code in server JS file:

```
app.post('/confirm', function (req, res) {
   // Here I need to send socket with emit()
});
```

Below mentioned code I have Socket.io:

```
io.on('connection', function (client) {
   // All methods
});
```

Problem is that I can not get access to `socket` in express method `app.post()` and can not send data by POST action.

How can I use that?

Comment: You should keep them separate because socket.io uses ws & wss protocol while express method uses http & htpps

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6bXpq1xiDsQ

Answer (score 0):

You can emit data to specific connected sockets using the following:

```
io.to(socket_id).emit('something', {"bar":"foo"});
```

The "socket_id" variable is, as probably guessed, the socket.id from the connected socket.

You will probably have to store them along with some other identification in an array or object to send data to the correct clients later using express routes.

PS: As your code is

```
io.on('connection', function (client) {
   // All methods
});
```

you would use `client.id` to get the socket id.